# How to use a jar that uses Spring in common lib?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss

I'm really new to Spring and I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. Here's my prob :

I've exported a jar which uses Spring 2.5 to inject dependency to a class in another project called "business". There's an accessor which uses `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` to get the bean.

I've placed that jar in the `common/lib` of JBoss 4.2.

In a webapp, in a jsp, I get the accessor, and then call a method with it. The compilation is fine, but when I reach the jsp, I have a `NoClassDefFound` on `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

If I move the jar from the `common/lib` in the `webapp/lib`, I then have an `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.acegisecurity.AccessDeniedException`.

How can I make it work? Or is there another way to doing so?

Comment: spring.jar doesn't have security packages in it.

Comment: JBoss 4.2 doesn't have `common/lib` or `webapp/lib` directories... what are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be dependent on spring-security somehow. Download the spring-security jar.